# BeginInvoke not being executed

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have the next code on *Windows Forms*:

```
if (control.IsHandleCreated)
{
    if (control.InvokeRequired)
    {
        control.BeginInvoke(action);
    }
    else
    {
        action.Invoke();
    }
 }
```

*Debugging*, it enters to `InvokeRequired = false` and it works perfectly, but on production environment. Somehow it enters to `InvokeRequired = true`, so it should execute `BeginInvoke()` method.

It doesn't. It never enters the action. This script belongs to a *DataGrid* control, but having the same on different *DataGrids*, *Comboboxes*, etc on the same Form it does work; so it seems to be something expecific for this *DataGrid*.
Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: How did you determine that the action is never entered?  Did you put a breakpoint somewhere in the method `action` represents?  Or did you just step through and note that control didn't flow from the `BeginInvoke` call directly into the `action` code?  If the latter, that makes sense, because `BeginInvoke` merely cues up the action to be performed later, on the GUI thread, rather than calling it directly.

Comment: it may fail and swallow exception internally. You can try to check Exception s thrown(or something like that) performance counter

Comment: There are no less than 3 potential threading race bugs in this code.  It is a very strong anti-pattern to have no idea whether or not code runs on a worker thread and having no idea whether the window was created or destroyed.  This *will* go wrong sooner or later.  For one, the invoke queue is purged when the user or the UI thread closes the window.  Actions that entirely unsynchronized with the thread execution.  If you write code like this then it must be entirely acceptable to have the invoke not complete.

Comment: @Hans Passant could you point to the three race conditions in the code? Because I am not seeing any. The action will by invoked in the UI thread, or not at all (if the control has no handle or the form is closed). If it is invoked it will be synchronous. There is no possibility for background threads preempting each other and corrupting the form's state. All background invocations are marshaled to the UI thread and executed there one after the other. Also I assume by the way the code is written that the case of purging an action is not critical for the application.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to find the true answer , my guess is that when you call begininvoke a message gets put in a queue for that thread. That thread takes items out of this queue and processes them 1 by 1. Let's say that you are calling BeginInvoke faster than the processing thread can handle it ... your queue will get bigger and bigger and take more and more time to process. then the main thread can become blocked doing other things. While your thread is doing these other things it will not be processing items out of the queue, then the thread can not access the control.
I tested your code, the code can not repeat in case of lack of access, then i changed the code and it works after repeat one or two times:

```
int i = 0;
    public delegate void AsyncMethodCaller();
    private  void proc2()
    {
        Action action = () => control1.Text = (i += 1).ToString();

        if (control1.IsHandleCreated)
        {
            if (control1.InvokeRequired)
            {
                control1.BeginInvoke(new AsyncMethodCaller(proc2));
            }
            else
            {
                action.Invoke();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Handle creation error");
        }
    }

    private void proc1()
    {
        for (int i=0; i<1000; i++)
        {
            //do something
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread thread1 = new Thread(proc1);
        thread1.Start();

        Thread thread2 = new Thread(proc2);
        thread2.Start();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I just used:

```
<your control>.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate () {
   … do your work here
}));
```

-Gina